# How to access class variable inside Promise then() function?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular-promise

I'm working on a Angular4 + PHP website, where i send HTTP requests to the server using Promise, since i want my application to perform routing according to the response of the server. I want to access a class variable inside the then() but it throws `undefined()` error.

Here is my code:

```
status = false;

checkUser(): Promise<any>{
// .....
    return this.http
        .get('http://localhost:8000/api/user', this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: any) {
    data = res.json();
    this.status = data.status; // here it throws error undefined 
    return this.status; 
}
```

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Again. Change `this.extractData` to `res => this.extractData(res)`. This question is being asked again and again.

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes, I do agree, its been asked quite many times, but as a beginner to angular,typescript its very hard to follow up others code, hope you can understand :)

Comment: Sure. I've done this mistake myself. But google is your friend. Googling for the title of your question and clicking on the first few results would have given you the answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you! Yeah I'll follow it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you pass a function reference, `this` won't point to the local class instance anymore.

You can use `bind`

```
.then(this.extractData.bind(this))
```

or arrow functions

```
.then((res) => this.extractData(res))
```

to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). It works